# '7' Runtime Error-NoSuchElementError-Element not found

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

Would you help me to know what I am missing?
Using Selenum driver, I wnat to automate collecting prices of specific products by sendkeys, search button click via the search fuction on the website - boulanger.com.

```
sub BLG()
...

    url = "https://www.boulanger.com/"
    driver.Start "Chrome"
    driver.Get url

    For i = 1 To ModelCnt
        modelcode = LCase(Cells(4 + i, 3).Value)
        driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=""search__component""]//div[1]/div/form/input").SendKeys modelcode
        driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=""search__component""]//div[1]/div/form/button").Click
...
    Next i

end sub
```

when executing the VBA codes, I have this error.

'7' Runtime Error-NoSuchElementError-Element not found

The Xpath of search box is as below;

`//*[@id="search__component"]//div[1]/div/form/input`
`/html/body/header/div/div/div[3]/section/bl-search//div[1]/div/form/input`

**What I want to do is put the model code by `.Sendkey modelcode` to the server and get search result but sticked at finding the correct element.**

(https://www.boulanger.com/)

Tried to use `FineElementbyCSS`, `FindElementbyXPath` but still not working

Comment: Please give an example of a specific product you want to search for and get the price.

Comment: Actually, I want to extract the prices of "HW-Q990C" and "HT-A7000" but in the very first step, I am blocked with that "NoElementError Element not found for Xpath=....." Err when using the CSS or Xpath extracted from that WEB site...

Comment: Now I found some clue that was related to Shadow DOM... But still finding way to Sendkey to one of tags in shadow root....

Comment: Tried this but had a javascript error as " shadowRoot.getElementByClassName is not a function" by this :    driver.ExecuteScript "var shadowRoot=arguments[0].shadowRoot; shadowRoot.getElementByClassName('search-input').value='modelcode'", driver.FindElementById("search__component")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This VBA code works for me. I had to build it up step by step, the click in the search box was the hardest to figure out.

```
Option Explicit

Sub sbBLG()
    Dim chr As ChromeDriver
    Set chr = New ChromeDriver
    Dim we As WebElement
    Dim sURL As String
    sURL = "https://www.boulanger.com/"
    Dim sModelCode As String
    sModelCode = "HT-A7000"
    chr.Start "Chrome"
    chr.Get sURL
    chr.Window.Maximize
    sbDelay (100000)
    chr.SwitchToFrame (0)
    Set we = chr.FindElementByXPath("/html/body")
    we.FindElementById("btnAll-on").Click
    chr.SwitchToParentFrame
    Set we = chr.FindElementByXPath("/html/body")
    sbDelay (100000)
    we.FindElementById("search__component").Click
    we.FindElementById("search__component").SendKeys sModelCode
    Dim Keys As Selenium.Keys
    Set Keys = New Selenium.Keys
    we.FindElementById("search__component").SendKeys Keys.Enter
    sbDelay (100000)
    Set we = chr.FindElementByXPath("/html/body")
    MsgBox we.FindElementByClass("price__amount").Attribute("outerHTML")
    MsgBox we.FindElementByClass("price__amount").Text
    chr.Quit
End Sub
Sub sbDelay(delay As Long): Dim i As Long: For i = 1 To delay:  DoEvents: Next i: End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot eating-popcorn. You showed me a good idea to skip dealing with a shadow DOM!